# В чем различия нативного OpenGL от его реализации в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

В чем различия нативного OpenGL от его реализации в Qt?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ни в чем. Там тот же самый openGL, просто с обертками для стыковки с Qt и инициализации.

Comment: верю , спасибо.